# Powershell XML Attribute

Tags: xml, powershell

I have several XML file that I need to read and set variable data from the node values.

example XML:

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
<Obj RefId="0">
<TN RefId="0">
  <T>System.__ComObject#{86fd1ebe-92e2-40f3-9c03-e5f0ca55f8ab}</T>
  <T>System.__ComObject</T>
  <T>System.MarshalByRefObject</T>
  <T>System.Object</T>
</TN>
<ToString>System.__ComObject</ToString>
<Props>
  <S N="Name">copy1234</S>
</Props>
```

The script I'm writing must read the file and get the value "copy1234" into a variable.  I suck, though, so it just returns NULL...

```
    Get-ChildItem $ImportFolderPath -Filter *.xml | Foreach-Object {
    $currentFile = $_.FullName
    Write-Host "Processing file:   $currentfile"
    [xml]$ccXML = Get-content $currentFile


    $ccName = Select-Xml -Path $currentfile -Xpath '//objs/obj/props/S[@N="Name"]'

        Write-Host "Name of node:  $ccName"
```

Comment: `Select-Xml -Path $currentfile -Xpath '/ns:Objs/ns:Obj/ns:Props/ns:S[@N="Name"]' -Namespace @{ns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04'}`

Comment: Ok, this is a lot closer, but it now returns:

value:FileFullPath

I just need 'value'.  I don't understand why it's joining the file name path.

Comment: You need to inspect what kind of object `Select-Xml` return to you.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing the fact that **XPath is case-sensitive**.
So the expression should be

```
$ccName = Select-Xml -Path $currentfile -Xpath '//Objs/Obj/Props/S[@N="Name"]'
```

If `Objs` is your root element you could even simplify/optimize this by omitting the `//`(everywhere in the document) and using a `/`(relative to root element):

```
$ccName = Select-Xml -Path $currentfile -Xpath '/Objs/Obj/Props/S[@N="Name"]'
```

Comment: Still returns NULL..... But, yes, you are right. I did forget the XPath casing.  Thanks!